# Series and Sequences Train Question

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

There's a question here that put me off, it differs from the normal AP/GP questions asked.

A train is travelling at $180 \text { km/h }$, $500\text { m }$ away from a train station, what is the constant deceleration needed to get to a complete stop at the station.

Comment: The use of the word ratio is very peculiar in this context. It should be constant acceleration (or deceleration),

Comment: Is my answer correct?

Comment: The acceleration is very different from the answer you give. But it is no clear what the question is asking for, if it really says ratio.

Comment: It must be a poorly written exam then, if ratio changed to constant deceleration, how would you do this question using arithmetic progression or geometric progression?

Comment: You and I can solve the constant deceleration problem using traditional velocity-distance-acceleration relations. It can be translated to series language, Galileo did it, but that introduces unnecessary complication. And it would not be answering the question in the OP, at least not the original wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solve the problem in its current incarnation, with no confidence of a connection with the original.

Let the acceleration be $a$, and let the time of travel be $t$.  Then the distance travelled is $180t+\frac{1}{2}at^2$. Thus 
$$180t+\frac{1}{2}at^2=\frac{1}{2}\tag{1}$$
In time $t$ velocity goes from $180$ to $0$. So 
$$at=-180\tag{2}.$$
Substituting the value of $at$ into (1) we get $t=1/180$, so $a=-180^2$. Units are km/hr$^2$, untraditional. Might want to translate to m/sec$^2$. We get $-2.5$.

Comment: Thank you, why would this question be in my topic exam, I have never done physics before.

Comment: You are welcome. It is a puzzle, So this is in the AP GP chapter? One can interpret, Galileo style, constant acceleration as meaning that the intervals covered in successive equal time chunks form an AP, but that is a more sophisticated approach than the one I took.

Comment: My teacher actually said the question in fact was 'ratio'. He used the limiting sum formula of a geometric series, used a=50 (in meters per second). He said he made the limiting sum = 500, so r (ratio) is -9/10